# How can I Install gbs from downloaded git gbs clone in my hard disk?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

In my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit I downloaded a gbs package clone from Server.

```
git clone git://git.tizen.org/tools/gbs
```

I now want to install it but the following command doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install gbs
```

I guess that my config file has problems. Then, how can I install it by using the downloaded files? without Network Connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find installation instructions for Ubuntu here - no need to clone it from git:

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.platform.development/html/platform_dev_env/gbs_installation.htm

Comment: URL not found. Please correct it.